# Jasper report error when run mass request

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Currently, in my project, we try to export file pdf using jasper

The code looks like this

```
{
    ...
    //report Folder and path define here
    String reportFolder = env.getProperty(APIConstant.PATH_REPORT_TEMPLATE);
    String reportPath = reportFolder + prdcode + APIConstant.FILE_TYPE_JASPER;
    ...
    printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(reportPath, params);
    if (printFileName != null) {
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName, illufilename); //Exception come from this line
    }
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

The problem comes when I try a performance test using JMeter, set up a thread of 50 user call at once. And the exception is

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file: D:\workspace\document\Report\ULP1.jrprint.
java.io.EOFException ....
```

One point is the `printFileName` is the same on all 50s calls?

Update full error log:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file: D:\workspace\document\Report\ULP1.jrprint.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:144)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(JRLoader.java:107)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:130)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:491)
at com.generali.print.common.service.impl.PrintManagerServiceHandlerImpl.compileAndDisplayReport(PrintManagerServiceHandlerImpl.java:1063)
at com.generali.servicemanager.common.AbstractServiceCommonClass.compileAndDisplayReport(AbstractServiceCommonClass.java:661)
at com.generali.servicemanager.common.service.impl.BIManagerServiceImpl.saveAndValidateIllustration(BIManagerServiceImpl.java:688)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1824.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy179.saveAndValidateIllustration(Unknown Source)
at com.generali.api.controller.BIController.updateAndValidateIllustrationDetailById(BIController.java:306)
at com.generali.api.controller.BIController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$840af0e1.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669)
at com.generali.api.controller.BIController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3aa8f960.updateAndValidateIllustrationDetailById(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1822.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2681)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:3180)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHandle(ObjectInputStream.java:1684)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1745)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:561)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintElement.readObject(JRTemplatePrintElement.java:374)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1926.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1304.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1304.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1304.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:561)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint.readObject(JasperPrint.java:1039)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1978.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:140)
... 65 common frames omitted
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) `D:\workspace\document\Report\ULP1.jrprint` - How this file related to your code? 2) What is a full stacktace? 3) What version of JR are you using?

Comment: 1/ That direction is `printFileName`  3/ jasper 6.7.0. 2/ will add full stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point you should not call `JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile`, instead of that you should call `JasperFillManager.fillReport` , should let `jasper` handle the file itself.

```
//printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(reportPath, params);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params);
if (jasperPrint != null) {
    //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName, illufilename);
     JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, illufilename);
}
```